# How to implement Infitine View Pager +Tab in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I want to implement infinite ViewPager with Tabs(ViewPager Indicator) in android.

I found many sample project,all of which include only ViewPager. I need to integrate infite ViewPager with Tabs.

Some of samples I have found:

1.)https://github.com/antonyt/InfiniteViewPager

2.)https://gitorious.org/thehayro-tutorials/thehayro-tutorials/source/c98c87bdb600d23ddfb195cffb9814097df73555:InifiniteViewPagerExample

Any help or idea will be appreciated.

Comment: i had use with sherlock library..you can check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755349/getsupportactionbar-returns-null/18755794#18755794

Comment: if you are going to show fragments inside the viewpager, using FragmentStatePagerAdapter and Overriding destroyItem would be a clever idea to prevent some performance problems.

Comment: You should try this at least once https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: @Andrain I have already tried but It cant work because  there are  infinite viewPager and indicator tries to create infinite tab...

Comment: @AndroidDev I can't see any relationship bw the question you have depicted and my question.

Comment: You can restrict as per your requirement by editing his main activity. i m also using this library and i have only 6 (tab + viewpager). @ibrahimyilmaz

Comment: @Andrain I need infinite scrolling like this, A->B->C, B->C->A, C->A->B, A->B->C.